# why is the swiftUI list not lazy (compared to lazyVStack)?

Tags: swift, list, lazy-loading, lazyvstack

are lists in SwiftUI really lazy?
I am having a list of 5000 elements fetched from coreData and I want to display them in a list. I read a lot of comments (like that: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651256) that Lists are lazy but for me it looks like they are not.... Loading the list takes 15 seconds.

```
List(element,  id: \.objectID, selection: $selection) { file in 
    RowView(file)
}
```

If I use a ScrollView + LazyVStack + ForEach instead the loading takes less than a second.

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
         ForEach(element, id: \.objectID) { file in
             RowView(file)
                .onTapGesture {
                    selection = Set([file.objectID])
                }
         }
    }
}
```

I would prefer taking a list to make use of the functionalities it provides.
Am I doing something wrong or is list not lazy?

Thanks for help!
(i am working with SwiftUI (for Mac)).

Comment: It's lazy on iOS but not on macOS (yet).

Comment: Thanks! Is there an option for Mac to make a list lazy?

Comment: You can use TableView instead, that's lazy on Mac

Comment: your resolution helps me a lot.

Comment: is there an option to make a non lazy list on iOS?